# Where to find further BlueZ logging and debugging output

Tags: linux, bluetooth, kernel, bluez, imx6

I am working on an embedded Bluetooth project where I have a Nordic MCU (Slave) and an iMX6 SoM based board as master running Linux for ARM. Now a basic

```
bluetoothctl
scan on
pair AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF #not the real MAC-address
```

does work on our development machines but fails with an instant `AuthenticationFailed` error on the iMX6 board. Beacons and their data are received just fine.

Neigther `dmesg` nor `journalctl` do give helping output so I would like to ask you if there is  any additional logging/debugging output ressource where I can look to narrow down the cause?

Best regards

Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how you are starting `bluetoothd`.

If you are starting the daemon manually, then you can use the `-d` options.
http://manpages.org/bluetoothd/8

Otherwise, use `btmon` in another terminal. http://manpages.org/btmon

`bluetoothctl` communicates with `bluetoothd` using D-Bus which can be monitored with `dbus-monitor --system`. http://manpages.org/dbus-monitor

Comment: `btmon` was what brought me onto the right track in the end. Turned out to be features on the slave side, that the host did not implement (it's a pretty old kernel version).